# what is proper way to update vao/vbo between thread?

Tags: opengl, multiprocessing, vbo, vao

Here is the problem I came across:

I read 3d model data in a thread and render it in main thread.
What is the proper way to create or update vao/vbo data?

Currently I set a bool value to indicate that whether main thread need to update vbo data, like this:

```
void RenderModel(){

    if(isNeedUpdateVBO){
        updateVBOData();
        isNeedUpdateVBO = false
    }

// render models here
}
```

I think there may be more efficient way to do that.

Comment: I do not want to use sharelist and do no want to create vbo/vao in thread, is there any efficient way?